# How do I use wp_get_recent_posts?

Tags: recent-posts

I'm trying to display the title and excerpt of the most recent 8 posts on the sidebar.

I'm getting a list where:

- All items link to the oldest post
- All titles are "id number of a post that should be displayed"+"oldest post title"
- All excerpts are from the oldest post

---

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '8' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        $noticias_highlight = true;

        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ 
?>
                    <div class="entry <?php if ($noticias_highlight) echo 'highlight'; $noticias_highlight = !$noticias_highlight; ?>">
                        <div class="title"><p><a href="<?php the_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>"><?php the_title($recent["ID"]); ?></a></p></div>
                        <div class="subtitle"><?php the_excerpt($recent["ID"]); ?></div>
                    </div>
<?php
        } 
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use the 'helper' methods, they tend to cause more trouble than they're worth.

Any time you want to grab posts, be it the latest, the oldest, in a category etc, use a `WP_Query` loop, here is its standard form:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do stuff
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // none were found
}
```

This is what `wp_recent_posts` will be doing internally, although it isn't doing it very well. So save the above to an autocomplete macro in your editor

Answer (score 1):

Many mistakes in the question's code:

- `the_permalink()` takes no arguments and returns the link of the *current* post. Use `echo get_permalink()` instead.
- `the_title()` prints the title of the *current* post, and its first argument is a string to be printed before the title. That's what causing the titles to be all the same but containt the numeric IDs for the correct posts. Use `echo get_the_title()` instead.
- `the_excerpt()` takes no arguments and prints the excerpt of the *current* post. I don't know if there's a similar function that accepts he post ID as an argument.

Most importantly:

- `wp_get_recent_posts()` will return an array containing one array for each post (hence the `foreach`). So instead of `the_title()` or `get_the_title()` the title can be returned via `$array[post_title]`, the excerpt via `$array[post_excerpt]` (will be empty if no excerpt is present, won't automatically truncate the post content), `$array[post_content]` for the post content, etc.
- `wp_get_recent_posts()` doesn't seem to use a wordpress loop. So functions that use the current post will always use the same post. That's what happens in the example.

And ***even*** most importantly:

- [Use `WP_Query()` instead](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) of `wp_get_recent_posts()`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Display Posts shortcode in your sidebar markup.  The plugin is here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/

Comment: I prefer not using a plugin for simple functionality that can be achieved in a few lines of code.

Comment: Not everyone who reads wordpress.stackoverflow lives in the PHP code. Some folks are just interested in getting things done. Why penalize alternate solutions?